# Which webservices are used in android development?

Tags: android, web-services

I am new at this platform could anyone tell me which webservice i should use in android?

Comment: it depends on for what purpose you are developing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Rest-Services are best alternative of all.

Comment: Sir if I want an app which is basically a forum where you could question and comment just like stackoverflow which web service should i use?

Comment: you can use restservice in this case also.